# Choice type implementation in F#

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I am fairly new in F# and having some problems with choice type implementation.
I have three types.

```
type A = p of string
type B = {q:string;r:int}
type C = s of string
```

Then I've a choice type like this.

```
type D = A | B | C
```

Now I am having problems in creating D type of variable. I am trying to do something like this,

```
let v = {q="abc";r=12}
let vofD = D.B v
```

But it gives this error,

> This value is not a function and cannot be applied

I have tried to search for documentation on this thing and it seems that I'm unable to find any good document or solution on this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the F# compiler doesn't understand that `D.B` refers to type `B`. If you define your discriminated union like this:

```
type D =
   | FromA of A
   | FromB of B
   | FromC of C
```

Then you can write `let vofD = D.FromB v`.

Comment: Or just "B of B" in the type, as we normally do. And then just "B v" to create it.

Comment: If you go to this [link](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/conciseness-type-definitions/) then you would find they have done the same thing with the Address type. What it is missing is how to assign value and I'm wondering whether there is a way to do that without having to write of in every choice.

Comment: That's usually a great site, but I think that particular example is wrong. There's even a comment at the bottom from Pavel Gatilov raising the same issue you did.

Comment: @brianberns Thank you for that. I've raised an issue on the [fsharpforfunandprofit](github.com/swlaschin/fsharpforfunandprofit.com) repository. For now, I'll use unions with of.